# Kint function not working for me at twig template

Tags: theming

I have enabled devel module and also enabled devel kint . From configuration section (development/devel) , I select kint as Variables Dumper. I also enable twig debug mode. But

```
{{ kint() }}
```

not working for me. Displaying error i.e

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Twig\Node\Expression\ArrayExpression::addElement() must be an instance
>   of Twig\Node\Expression\AbstractExpression, instance of
>   Twig\Node\CheckToStringNode given, called in
>   C:\wamp64\www\meme_v3\vendor\twig\twig\src\Node\Expression\CallExpression.php
>   on line 193 in Twig\Node\Expression\ArrayExpression->addElement()
>   (line 59 of vendor\twig\twig\src\Node\Expression\ArrayExpression.php).

Comment: you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_vardumper it's better .

Comment: when I am going to install it displaying -->  Twig Vardumper requires the symfony/var-dumper library.

Comment: I have also try with composer , authentication require from git.drupal.org

Comment: how to install symfony/var-dumper library ??

Comment: Install the vardumper with composer it will install it's dependencies `composer require 'drupal/twig_vardumper:^1.2' `

Comment: Yes , I know the command .. But when I going to run this command , displaying  :
Authentication required (git.drupal.org):

Comment: Normally it shouldn't, you can install symfony/var-dumper like the following `composer require --dev symfony/var-dumper `